# How to resolve dependecies while running a shell script remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

I'm trying to run a shell script remotely. I'm having a resource(.txt file) in one machine and a shell script in another machine, but in the same network. The script resides in a particular directory and the script takes some binary files that resides in some other directory everything in the target machine. Now, I'm not able to run the script remotely. But I can run a simple shell program which does not have any local dependencies. Can you please suggest a solution to resolve this problem?

Here is the command that I used for running a shell-script-without-any-dependencies.

```
cat input.txt | ssh clrg@192.168.2.22  "sh path/to/shell/script/tokenize.sh"
```

On running a script with dependencies, I got the following error,

```
"ambiguous redirect"  
../../deter-4/bin/determine: No such file or directory  
../../deter-4/bin/determine1: No such file or directory
```

Now, how can I tell to accept dependencies while running the shell script

Comment: Please elaborate on "I'm not able to run the script remotely".  Describe your observations when you try to do this.

Comment: @Alfe I'm getting an error "ambiguous redirect" as there are statements in the script such as ../../deter-4/bin/determine. For these statements, I'm getting "No such file or directory" error. It's clear that the program couldn't resolve dependencies. Unfortunately, I don't know how to give the path while doing it remotely

Comment: The title doesn't really have anything to do with the question -- dependency resolution wasn't in any way related to the actual problem. Perhaps it could be edited to something more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is the working directory.  Try something like this:

```
cat input.txt | ssh clrg@192.168.2.22  "sh -c 'cd /path/to/shell/script; ./tokenize.sh'"
```

Your script seems to expect to be run from a specific working directory only.  The error messages you mentioned in your comment about the relative paths (starting with `../../`) at least suggest that.

Comment: The `sh -c '...'` is unnecessary; the argument to `ssh` is passed to the login shell, so can be an arbitrary sequence of shell commands.

Comment: Right, @chepner.  I wasn't too sure about that semicolon, so I took the save path.  But I tend to agree now.

Comment: @Alfe The above method is working fine and the script throws the output to the console. But when I tried to save it to the file using a redirect(> output.txt), I'm getting a message that says "ambiguous redirect". How should I save/write the output to a file?

Comment: What exactly did you type?  I'll need the whole line.  Currently I think you might have used both `|` and `>` on the same command; that would be an ambiguous redirect.  Or you used `>` twice.

Comment: @Alfe I simply added `>` at the end of above command and that gave me "ambiguous redirect". How can I safely write the output to a file?

Comment: add a file name: `... > bla`

Comment: @Alfe  Even after trying that, I still get `ambiguous redirect` error. Is there any other way?

Comment: I can't explain that error, no.  It can be that the `./tokenize.sh` gives out that message of course.  But then it should not depend on the `>` after the command.  By best guess is that you mistyped something.  Maybe you open another question for this?  Sounds interesting enough to draw attention, and maybe others have better ideas.  Here, probably only me is reading your questions.